# Does the story of LoS integrates with the rest of the franchise?

Tags: castlevania-lords-of-shadow, castlevania-symphony-of-the-night

I'm a huge fan of the Castlevania franchise. I played nearly all of the games, my favorites being Aria of Sorrow and Symphony of the Night. I didn't want to play the Lord of Shadows game serie because of its gameplay and "level design". Unlike Order of Ecclesia where you have several levels but need to come back to some of them with new abilities, LoS concentrates on the "one shot level" system (I'm inventing a lot of terms right now I think).

I started by playing the 3DS game (LoS Mirror of Fate) and found the story truly captivating, we learn the origins of Alucard, and lots of other things. Next, I played the first LoS game, the story is amazing too, but now I wonder, does the story of LoS integrates with the other games or is it a totally different story ? I did a bit of research but it seems I can't google correctly.

Could anyone tell me if the story of LoS (the whole game serie, including LoS, LoS:MF, LoS2) matches the story of the other Castlevania games ? (Especially with the Belmont chronology or things like that)

I didn't play LoS2 so I'd like to avoid spoilers about that particular game. Thanks !

Comment: And obviously after asking the question, I find the answer. Damn. http://www.videogamer.com/ps3/lords_of_shadow/preview-1975.html
“It's not part of the so-called timeline. This is an original, standalone product. We didn't want to follow the timeline because we felt it would put us in a bit of a box in terms of what we could do creatively. We didn't want to be in that box.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, the Lord of Shadows series doesn't integrate with the rest of the series.  It was a series reboot.

[Lament of Innocence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castlevania:_Lament_of_Innocence) is the origin story of Dracula in the original series.  Just like Lord of Shadows is the origin story of Dracula in the new series.  The two games are completely contradictory.